# Unable to retrieve AllocationId attribute for AWS::EC2::EIP, with error message Address '34.215.102.177' not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, testrail

I am upgrading my Testrail to use CDKV2. I am able to deploy to Beta environment successfully. But when I deploy to prod environment, I see this error while deploying to TestrailVpc:

`Unable to retrieve AllocationId attribute for AWS::EC2::EIP, with error message Address '34.215.102.177' not found. (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 0b877023-d4aa-427f-980d-590ee21bf02a)`  
Does anyone know the root cause and fix for this?

Same thing run successfully on Beta environment.

Comment: That's seems to be related to the network settings - check that firewalls and AWS VPC settings are properly set